# Parsing a multiple choice parameter to an Outlook form using Python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

At my company, when I send an email using outlook, after hitting 'send' an 'On Action Event' is triggered which is a pop up titled 'select form' that asks for a selection from a dropdown. I select, then click 'ok' and the email sends.

After running the below code, the 'select form' pop up appears. I would like to find a way to populate the form from within the code so that the email sends without manual intervention

```
import win32com.client as win32
 
olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
 
# construct email item object
mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
mailItem.Subject = 'Hello 123'
mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
mailItem.Body = 'Hello There'
mailItem.To = '<recipient email>'
mailItem.Sensitivity  = 2
# optional (account you want to use to send the email)
mailItem._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, olNS.Accounts.Item('<senders email>')))
mailItem.Display()
#mailItem.Save()
mailItem.Send()
```

Comment: How does the dialog look like? Does it come from a third-party Outlook add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an Outlook add-in or VBA macro is working in your Outlook (for displaying such dialogs) because you are setting the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property in the code correctly. You may ask developers for any public interface that can be available to developers and which you may call from your script. For example, see [Walkthrough: Call code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.